# Regularized cox survival model with time varying covariates and sparce matrix in R

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, sparse, time-varying-covariate

I was wondering if there is a survival framework in R (or any other language for that matter) for doing the following:

1. Fitting an extended (i.e., time-varying covariates) cox survival model
2. Applying ridge regression to regularize the model parameters (or any other regularization is also fine - lasso, bayesian, etc.)
3. Specifying the X matrix [start stop status covariates...] as a sparse matrix

The motivation is that I have been performing a survival analysis, but the number of covariates is starting to grow, and for many of these covariates, they will be 0 for all or most of the customer history. If I don't formulate as a sparse matrix, the data size can get up into the 10ish GB range.